# TypeScript import syntax

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using [node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch) with TypeScript.

I want to access the fetch function and also the Resource interface which are defined in the type definition as:

```
export default function fetch(url: string | Request, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response>;
```

and

```
export class Response extends Body {
    // ...
}
```

In my TypeScript file I'm importing these separately using:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { Response } from 'node-fetch';
```

Is there a nicer, single line way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax?

```
import fetch, { Response } from 'node-fetch';
```